# Laravel what does mean "Undefined array key client_secret"

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

So, I am trying to use the Google Login API for my web application. But the problem is, it doesn't work. I successfully installed the package Socialite and Auth. My Google OAuth2.0 is setuped. But when I click on the button Login with google, it gives me an error that I understand, but don't know how to fix. I'm searching this error for now 2 days on internet and I didn't find anything, that's why I'm posting now. Can someone help me ? Or put me on the right track :) I am using Laravel 8.0

**Here is the problem that I get**
[image: Laravel Socialite Error]
[image: What they give me on the browser]

**Here is the function (both gives the same error)**

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    //return($provider);
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
    Auth::login($authUser, true);
    return $user->token;
}
```

**services.php**

```
    'google' => [
    'client_id'     => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect'      => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT')
],
```

**.env**

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
GOOGLE_REDIRECT=https://www.trivos.ca/home
```

Comment: Did you edit your `config/services.php` as mentioned in the docs?

Comment: Please don't post your code as images... Code is text, copy and paste it into the question so if we need to copy it, we can. Beyond that, you should have a config file for socialite, as defined in the Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite#configuration

Comment: Here is what I added in services.php     'google' => [
        'client_id'     => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect'      => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT')
    ],

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the relevant info there, so it is in one place. Did you set those in your `.env` file? Maybe run `php artisan config:clear` afterwards?

Comment: Oh, thx your command php artisan config:clear worked !!!! Can you explain me why this command worked, should I run this command everytime something isn't working and after that I should look on internet for solutions if it didn't worked ?

Comment: Yes, but for the moment I only use Google. I try to understand before setuping other providers

Comment: Deleted my follow-up comment, not relevant to your current setup, but if you do add other Provides (GitHub, etc.), make sure they have those 3 keys, and associated `.env` values, and you're good :) Also, for reference, this is what `config:cache` and `config:clear` does: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: Thanks for your help :D That really helped me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply needed to run php artisan config:clear